# JS script running via HTML button

Tags: javascript, forms, function, button

So I'm new to the programing world and I've been busting my head around this situation that I can't seem to figure out..
I have an HTML button and a function (if - else) and I want the function to "stop" and show the error when the input is not according to the format I want for the input

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/script.js"></script>
```

```js
let numecomplet = /^[A-Za-z ]*$/;
let formatemail = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
let numeprodus = /^[A-Za-z0-9]*$/;

function checkform() {
  var a = document.getElementById("nume").value;
  var b = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var c = document.getElementById("produs").value;

  if (a.match(numecomplet)){
    document.getElementById("nume").innerHTML = "";
  }else {
    document.getElementById("numegresit").innerHTML = "Nume incorect";
  }

  if (b.match(formatemail)){
    document.getElementById("email").innerHTML = "";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("emailgresit").innerHTML = "Email incorect";
  }
  
  if (c.match(numeprodus)) {
    document.getElementById("produs").innerHTML = "";
 } else {
    document.getElementById("prodgresit").innerHTML = "Nume produs incorect";
 }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="nume">Nume:</label>
      <input type="text" id="nume" name="nume" value="";><br>
          <p id="numegresit" style="color: blanchedalmond; font-size: 20px;"></p>

  <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" autocomplete="on" value="";><br>
          <p id="emailgresit" style="color: blanchedalmond; font-size: 20px;"></p>

  <label for="produs">Produs:</label>
      <input type="text" id="produs" name="produs" value="";><br>
          <p id="prodgresit" style="color: blanchedalmond; font-size: 20px;"></p>

  <button onclick="checkform()"> Submit </button>
</form>
```

I tried:

- `button > onclick=submit` instead of `onclick=checkform;`
- `return false;` at the end of the syntax (prior to last `{}`), after each `else` syntax
- `return true; + return false;` after `if`, respectively `else`
- without `<form></form>`

Also tried looking on Google, but since I'm newbie level some of the solutions seem too advanced and didn't understand much from them.

So I hope I can be clear enough with what I want the webpage to display... I want to see error text from `<p>` to stay on the webpage when `else` is "true", but the behavior I have now is that I see the text, but after that the page sort of reloads and the text disappears.

Comment: `document.getElementById("nume").innerHTML = "";` doesn't do anything. `<input>` elements don't have `innerHTML`. If you want to change the input, assign to `.value`.

Comment: Nothing in your function prevents the form from being submitted.

Comment: If you want to clear the error message, assign to `document.getElementById("numegresit").innerHTML`.

Comment: You need to pass `event` to the function, and call `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the form from submitting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop page from reloading on failed validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41255800/stop-page-from-reloading-on-failed-validation)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and [prevent default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) for that, like this:

```
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', (event) => {

      // Prevent submitting of the form

      event.preventDefault();

      // Validate

      if(checkform()){
 
           // Only submit it if it is valid
 
           document.querySelector('form').submit();
 
      }
 
});
```

For an interactive example see this implementation. Please note that I am using the if conditions and regex you provided, they may need some tweaking, i.e. the return value of the `checkform` function decides whether to submit the form (reload) or not.

```js
let numecomplet = /^[A-Za-z ]*$/;
let formatemail = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
let numeprodus = /^[A-Za-z0-9]*$/;

function checkform() {
  var a = document.getElementById("nume").value;
  var b = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var c = document.getElementById("produs").value;

  if (a.match(numecomplet)){
    document.getElementById("nume").innerHTML = "";
  }else {
    document.getElementById("numegresit").innerHTML = "Nume incorect";
  }

  if (b.match(formatemail)){
    document.getElementById("email").innerHTML = "";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("emailgresit").innerHTML = "Email incorect";
  }
  
  if (c.match(numeprodus)) {
    document.getElementById("produs").innerHTML = "";
 } else {
    document.getElementById("prodgresit").innerHTML = "Nume produs incorect";
 }
 
 // Return true or false based on your desired critera for validity
 
 return a.match(numecomplet) && b.match(formatemail) && c.match(numeprodus);
 
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', (event) => {

     // Prevent submitting of the form

     event.preventDefault();

     // Validate

     if(checkform()){
     
          // Only submit it if it is valid
     
          document.querySelector('form').submit();
     
     }
     
});
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="nume">Nume:</label>
      <input type="text" id="nume" name="nume" value="";><br>
          <p id="numegresit" style="color: blanchedalmond; font-size: 20px;"></p>

  <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" autocomplete="on" value="";><br>
          <p id="emailgresit" style="color: blanchedalmond; font-size: 20px;"></p>

  <label for="produs">Produs:</label>
      <input type="text" id="produs" name="produs" value="";><br>
          <p id="prodgresit" style="color: blanchedalmond; font-size: 20px;"></p>

  <button onclick="checkform()"> Submit </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the build-in form validation in HTML instead of creating your own on the submit event. Use the `required` attribute on the input elements. The form will not submit as long as some of the input elements are not valid. Use the `pattern` attribute to give the form validation something to evaluate the value against.

Then clicking the submit button the (build-in) validation will run and if an input is not valid you will get an `invalid` event on the element. This event can be used to give the user feedback -- like here changing the class name of the label (and CSS will do the rest of the work). Notice that the `useCapture` parameter is set to `true` on the method [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). This is to prevent the default message text to appear.

Then the value of an input change there will be an `input` event. Use that for evaluating the value again, and remove the className on the label if valid.

```js
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('invalid', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let label = e.target.closest('label');
  label.classList.add('error');
}, true);

document.forms.form01.addEventListener('input', e => {
  let label = e.target.closest('label');
  if(e.target.validity.valid){
    label.classList.remove('error');
  }
});
```

```css
p.feedback {
  color: blanchedalmond;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

label.error ~ p.feedback {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <label>Nume:
    <input type="text" name="nume"
      pattern="[A-Z-a-z ]*" required>
  </label>
  <p class="feedback">Nume incorect</p>
  <label>Email:
    <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="on"
      pattern="([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})" required>
  </label>
  <p class="feedback">Email incorect</p>
  <label>Produs:
    <input type="text" name="produs"
      pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]*" required>
  </label>
  <p class="feedback">Nume produs incorect</p>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```